# Handle failure response on SharePoint list item add using PnP JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs, react-webpart

I have created one SPFx web part with React framework to add the items from `.CSV` file to SharePoint list using PnP JS.

I have used PnP JS `item.add()` method to add the item in the list by looping each item.

If any item failed to add in the list I want to keep track of that item. I am using below code:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listdisplayname).items.add(
   ColumnInternalname : value
).catch((iar: ItemAddResult)  => {
    console.log(iar.data.responseBody["odata.error"].message.value, 
    iar.item);
})
```

But in the catch I got the response like below.

```
{"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","data":{"responseBody":{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Boolean'. See the inner exception for more details."}}},"responseHeaders":{}},"name":"ProcessHttpClientResponseException"}
```

Is it possible to get body (i.e. Parameter we passed in the `item.add()`) of that action?

Comment: The posted item should be in the `item` property of the `ItemAddResult`, maybe do a `console.log(iar)` to inspect the entire result object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not log the value directly?

```
console.log(value,iar.item);
```

Here is my debug screenshot which can be get from `ItemAddResult`

[image]